Eigenvalues of Cooper Pair Box with Matlab
I wanted to evaluate the eigenvalues of the Cooper Pair Box Hamiltonian in number basis
$$
\hat H=\sum_n 4E_c(n-n_g)^2 |n\rangle\langle n|-E_J/2(|n\rangle\langle n+1|+|n+1\rangle\langle n|)
$$
as a function of $n_g$ with Matlab. Basically I wanted to recreate this plot form Koch et al. 2007.

In order to do this I write the Hamiltonian as a matrix (there is a 4 multiplying $E_c$)

and for each value of $n_g$ Matlab evaluates the eigenvalues of the matrix. When $E_J/E_c=1$ the plot is the same

but when $E_J/E_c=50$ the first three eigenvalues are negative, while in the photo they are all positive. Is there something wrong with the code or is the reference photo wrong ? Could they be negative ? My opinion is that in the photo the eigenvalues are translated along y so that the first energy level is near zero.


Try solving for $E_c=0$, that is $E_J/E_c\rightarrow\infty$. In this case Hamiltonian is a semi-infinite tight-binding chain, exactly solvable. I don't remember the answer, but for an infinite tight-binding chain the spectrum has half of the states below zero: $\epsilon(k)\propto E_J\cos(k)$.
